# how to change username of all git commits after cloning a repo via gui or cmd

Tags: git, github

How do you change the 'author' and 'email address' of all the commits after cloning a repository from github?

And, can this also be done  via tortoise git or by a gui or only command line?

Comment: The answer is you don't, not unless you are prepared to rewrite the history of the comment for every commit.  May we ask why you want to make it look like someone else did all the work?

Comment: Im trying to clone a repository i started working on from a flatmates computer to a new laptop and would prefer my name rather than his.

Comment: Take a look the @codeWizard answer below.  This will be a lot of work and is not in the spirit of Git, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it of course but it will results in a new commit chain which will make the original repository **useless**.

You do it using `filter-branch` which will execute rebase, and again it will modify all your commit history which is actually a reabse.

---

*If you don't know what rebase is - don't do it.*

---

#### Filter branch to rename author/email

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<Old Name>" ];
    then
            GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<New Name>";
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<New Name>";
            GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<New Email>";
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<New Email>";
            git commit-tree "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD `
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a bit different way.

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='abc' GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='abc@gmail.com' GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='sabc' GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='sabc@gmail.com'" HEAD
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**